# Permission denied when trying to install asdf plugin on docker (github codespace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, docker, github, asdf

I have some script on a dockerfile that is aimed at installing the [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf)'s plugin ruby plugin on a [Github codespace's custome container](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/introduction-to-dev-containers) (using devcontainer.json, docker-compose, a dockerfile...).

Dockerfile:

```
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git $HOME/.asdf && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.profile
```

This first part works correctly. I'm sure because if I run just this RUN clock above, I can build my github codespace without any error and I'm also sure asdf did install because I check it via terminal of command

```
$ sudo su
$ asdf list
```

This outputs a message from asdf, showing it did install:

```
no plusins installed
```

But the second part below, where i try to install asdf's ruby plugin, gets an error:

```
RUN $HOME/.bashrc && \
    # install asdf ruby plugin
    asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git && \
    # add ruby version
    asdf install ruby $RUBY_VERSION && \
    # set our machine e.g our container's global Ruby version
    asdf global ruby $RUBY_VERSION
```

The error I get is:

```
 /bin/sh: 1: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

For a larger context on the error output, the terminal of command output shows:

```
#6 [ 3/11] RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git $HOME/.asdf &&     echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.bashrc &&     echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> $HOME/.bashrc &&     echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.profile
#6 0.746 Cloning into '/root/.asdf'...
#6 DONE 1.6s

#7 [ 4/11] RUN $HOME/.bashrc &&     asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git &&     asdf install ruby latest &&     asdf global ruby latest
#7 0.658 /bin/sh: 1: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
#7 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c $HOME/.bashrc &&     asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git &&     asdf install ruby $RUBY_VERSION &&     asdf global ruby $RUBY_VERSION]: exit code: 126
```

I tried different things for the first line of this RUN block, but I always run into some sorts of error:

If I do `RUN sudo $HOME/.bashrc`, I got the error

```
sudo: /root/.bashrc: command not found
```

If I do `RUN sudo su $HOME/.bashrc`, I got the error:

```
su: user /root/.bashrc does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields
```

If i do `RUN su vscode $HOME/.bashrc`, I got the error:

```
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

I'm very very early beginner on docker so I could not find how to bypass this and install ruby plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second RUN should be like this:

```
RUN bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc  && asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git && asdf install ruby RUBY_VERSION && asdf global ruby $RUBY_VERSION"
```

Yeah, it's ugly, but honestly I do not know if it's safe to break up to lines.

The key is you have to *source* your .bashrc to apply it to all remaining commands.

Comment: gosh!!! i fiddled with every possibility and features about permissions and stuff on dockerfile for a good 6 hours. I wasn't looking in the right place: you were right, your suggestion worked: it was just some line breaks!! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is file/script that is run every time you log in (open your terminal) and you can not run it like any other script manually.

You can try something like this `RUN exec $HOME/.bashrc` or `RUN source $HOME/.bashrc` instead just running it like any other script.

Comment: Thanks but I tried and I still get the core issue, the "permission " issue:. On your 2 suggestions I respectively get the following error message `/bin/sh: 1: exec: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied` and `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`

Comment: Try running "RUN sudo exec $HOME/.bashrc", also are you using linux alpine (because it is minimal version of linux and you can not run some commands without installing them ). Alpine linux is using ash shell and not bash. You can check how to install and add bash shell in this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/alpine-linux-install-bash-using-apk-command/. When I say using linux alpine I mean is your docker container on linux alpine, not your machine.